# What's the idiomatic way of describing the passage of a period of time equal to a few days?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the idiomatic way of describing the passage of a period of time equal to a few days?

> His ability to remember new words is just tremendous – he simply
>   doesn’t need things to be repeated for him or even reviewed **at some
>   latter time in a few days**.

The words put in bold in the example above, as I was told, not idiomatic in English, so what would be the most natural way of describing that thought?

Should it be like:

1) on the passage of a few days

2) on having a few days passed

3) in a few-days period

or there is some another better way?

Comment: Can't you replace your entire bolded phrase with the single word **later**?

Comment: @CanadianYankee - I can, but in this way it may mean "a few hours later".

Comment: If you really want to emphasize a time-span on the order of days, then "a few days later" is more idiomatic than your other examples.

Comment: I see. Thank you. The answer, as always, is simpler than I thought.